# Android Action bar Image

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to display one image in the Right most corner of action bar. I want this image to be set at runtime depending on some code checks. Can someone guide me how to go about it?

Thanks

Comment: Overflow menu from onCreateOptionsMenu() is one way to show images/icons but that cant be done at runtime I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this. This code adds a refresh button at top right with the icon called R.drawable.refresh. Will show the icon only if there's enough space, else it will show it on the menu

```
    private Menu myMenu

    public void changeMenu (int resource) {

    myMenu.getItem(0).setIcon(resource); //here resource is your R.drawable.insertid

    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    // getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
            myMenu = menu;
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    menu.add("Refresh").setIcon(R.drawable.refresh)
            .setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                                            doStuff();
                    return false;
                }
            }).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Just call changeMenu wherever you want to change the code and pass the drawable id.

Edit: Paste this on your activity and add the imports that ask you. You should add your own drawable according to what you want. Remember that icons measure

- mdpi: 32x32
- hdpi: 48x48
- xhdpi: 64x64

Comment: But this will fix one predefined image on action bar. As I said I want to load image at runtime based on some code.(The image to place varies according to code)

Comment: you still can do that with this code, just asociate the menu with a variable of your code, then call it like this "menu.getItem(0).setIcon(icon)" I will edit my answer

Answer (score -1):

if you want to change it at run time you need to make the menu (in onCreateOptionsMenu) and save the menu item. Like this

```
MenuItem changeableMenuItem = menu.add("new Item");
```

now you can call `changeableMenuItem.setIcon` to change the icon, then if you make `changeableMenuItem` a field in the class you can change the Icon anywhere in the class.

you can reference Dante's answer if you're not sure how to make the menu item.